# Custom dropdown view for iOS without using libraries

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, dropdown

I'd like to create a custom view to show validation errors and related details in an existing app. This will be used to display errors and related information when user inputs invalid input. I've seen many libraries for the same. I'd like to develop a custom view. What I thought of implementing was a view with height constraint set to zero and then when error appears, the view is populated and height constraint changed. But it seems not a best practice.

[image: Screen without alert]

[image: Screen with alert]

As seen from the images, a new view should drop down in the existing screen. Can someone give me a solution that I can implement which can be reused across the application?

Comment: One thing that you can do is create a view and put it on top of your App Delegate's window.

Comment: As per the design it should appear inside the existing view.

Comment: just need to add top constant equivalent to height of navigation bar, it will appear on top of the current view like overlay

Comment: It should appear within the view controller under the navigation bar.

Comment: Use a [UIStackView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview)